# Use sys.stdin to compare 2 lins in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapreduce

I am using python to do my MapReduce homework which will use sys.stdin as a reader of the input file. for example :

```
for line in sys.stdin:
     # compare 1st line with the 2ed line.
```

I can load all the file content into memory and use the index to implement a 2 lines comparasion for exmample:

```
lines= open("guru99.txt","r")
for i in range(len(lines)):
    if lines[i] != lines[i-1]:
       ...
```

My question is How to do these 2 lines comparison using sys.stdin way? As the homework file "guru99.txt" is huge and I can't load it into memory but only the sys.stdin way will work.

Comment: Can you think of a way to remember what the previous line was, while you get the current line from the loop? Put another way: can you think of a way to remember what the current line is, so that *when* you get the *next* line from the loop, you will have this line to compare it to?

Comment: Take 2 lines of input at a time? Use `next(sys.stdin)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the first line using `next` and then iterate the remaining input.

```
import sys

try:
    prev = next(sys.stdin)
except StopIteration:
    # no input
    exit()

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line == prev:
        do the things
    prev = line
```